# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.jboss.resteasy.specimpl.BuiltResponse.getHeaders()Ljavax/ws/rs/core/MultivaluedMap

Tags: maven, tomcat, servlets, jax-rs

I develop Restful web service. I want output as XML type(VXML). I try like this. I use Java 8, Maven, Jersey  and same as new technology. I get details  from that web address [link](http://blog.usul.org/using-jsp-in-a-jersey-jax-rs-restful-application/).

this my example code for request catch

```
@Path("/custemerservice")
public interface CustemerService {
    @GET
    @Path("no/123")
    @Consumes({ MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED })
    @Produces("text/html")
    public Response getWelcomeInfo();
}
```

and below this is development code

```
@Service
public class CustemerServiceImpl implements CustemerService {
    @Override
    public Response getWelcomeInfo() {
        Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        map.put("user", "usul");
        List<String> l = new ArrayList<String>();
        l.add("light saber");
        l.add("fremen clothes");
        map.put("items", l);
        return Response.ok(new Viewable("/cart.jsp", map)).build();
    }
}
```

this is my web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    version="3.0">
    <display-name>MyApp</display-name>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ResteasyBootstrap</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.spring.SpringContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>javax.ws.rs.core.Application</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>javax.ws.rs.core.Application</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/resteasy/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>WEB-INF/spring-hibernate-resteasy.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>resteasy.servlet.mapping.prefix</param-name>
        <param-value>/resteasy</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>com.ezakus.web</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.JSPTemplatesBasePath</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/jsp</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.WebPageContentRegex</param-name>
        <param-value>/(resources|(WEB-INF/jsp))/.*</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

</web-app>
```

and I edit pom.xml for that part development

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
            <version>1.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey.contribs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-multipart</artifactId>
            <version>1.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-json-provider</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
            <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.2</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
```

I try to run project using tomcat 8 in eclipse. I got error like this how to solve it.

> HTTP Status 500 - Servlet execution threw an exception
>
> type Exception report
>
> message Servlet execution threw an exception
>
> description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it
>   from fulfilling this request.
>
> exception
>
> javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet execution threw an exception
>     org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>
> root cause
>
> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   org.jboss.resteasy.specimpl.BuiltResponse.getHeaders()Ljavax/ws/rs/core/MultivaluedMap;
>     org.jboss.resteasy.core.ServerResponseWriter.setDefaultContentType(ServerResponseWriter.java:186)
>     org.jboss.resteasy.core.ServerResponseWriter.writeNomapResponse(ServerResponseWriter.java:46)
>     org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.writeResponse(SynchronousDispatcher.java:427)
>     org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:376)
>     org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:179)
>     org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:220)
>     org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:56)
>     org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:51)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
>     org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>
> note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache
>   Tomcat/8.0.23 logs. Apache Tomcat/8.0.23

this is eclipse log .

Thanks.

Comment: Do you call this API from the browser and get this exception? What is that URL?

Comment: http://localhost:8080/MyApp/resteasy/custemerservice/no/123 this is browser get Url. but get out put as that error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like you use a version 1 of `resteasy-jaxrs.jar`. The Method `getHeaders()Ljavax/ws/rs/core/MultivaluedMap;`was introduced in version 2.

So you have to change to version 2 of the  `resteasy-jaxrs.jar` which contains the class `org.jboss.resteasy.specimpl.BuiltResponse`

Comment: @ThilinaSampath See the second paragraph

Comment: I try that way my total project not working. how to I solve it.

Comment: @ThilinaSampath have you added the dependency to your pom.xml?

Comment: @ThilinaSampath which version of `javax.ws.rs.jar` do you use?

Comment: /WEB-INF/lib/resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.8.Final.jar that is jar I use for resteasy-jaxrs.jar

Comment: @ThilinaSampath and javax.ws.rs.jar ?

Comment: It looks like MultivaluedMap has been moved to "resteasy-multipart-provider", and I had a similar issue: "NoSuchMethodError: ...InputPart.getHeaders()". The solution was to change from version 6.2.1.Final to 3.0.10.Final on WildFly 17.

Answer (score 0):

It didn´t recognize the annotation @Produces("text/html").

Use Response.status(Response.Status.OK).type(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)